# Functional derivative identity

Tags: functional-analysis, variational-analysis

Is my proof of the following identity correct?

> Let the functional $F[\Psi(\xi);x,y]$ be the inverse of the functional
> $G[\Psi(\xi); x, y]$ in the following sense:
>
> $\displaystyle \int dz F[\Psi(\xi);x,z] G[\Psi(\xi); z, y] = \delta(x- y), \quad \forall \Psi(\xi) \qquad (1)$
>
> Why is the following identity true:
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{\delta F[\Psi(\zeta);x,y]}{\delta \Psi(z)} = -\int d\xi d\eta F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi]\frac{\delta G[\Psi(\zeta); \xi, \eta]}{\delta \Psi(z)}F[\Psi(\zeta);\eta,y] \qquad (2)$

**Proof**:

Changing the dummy variables in (1) we have:

$\displaystyle \int d\xi F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi] G[\Psi(\zeta); \xi, \eta] = \delta(x - \eta)$

Taking the variation of the previous equation and multiplying by $F[\Psi(\zeta);\eta,y]$ we obtain:

$\displaystyle \int d\xi \Bigg\{ \frac{\delta F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi]}{\delta \Psi(z)}G[\Psi(\zeta); \xi, \eta]F[\Psi(\zeta);\eta,y] \\\displaystyle+ \frac{\delta G[\Psi(\zeta); \xi, \eta]}{\delta \Psi(z)}F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi]F[\Psi(\zeta);\eta,y]\Bigg\} = 0$

which integrated with respect to $\eta$ yields:

$\displaystyle \int d\xi \frac{\delta F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi]}{\delta \Psi(z)}\delta(\xi - y) + \int\int d\xi d\eta F[\Psi(\zeta);x,\xi]\frac{\delta G[\Psi(\zeta); \xi, \eta]}{\delta \Psi(z)}F[\Psi(\zeta);\eta,y] = 0$

where we have made use of (1) once again. Using the sifting property of the delta funcion leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first identity can be written as $FG=I,$ where $I$ is the identity kernel. We also assume that $GF=I.$ Taking derivatives of both sides gives $(FG)' = 0,$ i.e $F'G+FG'=0,$ leading to $F'G=-FG'.$ Multiply both sides with $F$ from the right to get $F'GF=-FG'F,$ i.e. $F'=-FG'F$ since $GF=I.$

Comment: Ups, I was editing the question and didn't see your answer. I did something similar.

Comment: I noted that the question suddenly was closed when I was writing an answer. But later it existed again so I finished my answer.

Comment: Well, I like the idea of using an identity kernel. Looks very neat, great answer.

Comment: It's just like a matrix multiplication. Instead of $(FG)_{ik} = \sum_j F_{ij} G_{jk}$ we have $(FG)(x,z)=\int F(x,y) G(y,z) \, dy.$ And often $F,G$ are functions of some parameter $t$, but here they are instead function(al)s of a function $\Psi.$